# PUT not working with SpringDataRest

Tags: json, spring, spring-data-rest, put

So I am building a REST api using SpringDataRest both Get and Post are working but I don´t know whats wrong with the PUT.

This is the entity im using:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "companies") 
public class Company {

@Id
@Column(name="CompanyId", nullable=false, unique=true)
private String companyId;

@Column(name="Name", nullable=false)
private String name;

@Column(name="ContactName", nullable=false)
private String contactName;

@Column(name="ContactSurName")
private String contactSurname;

@Column(name="ContactEmail", nullable=false)
private String contactEmail;

@Column(name="ContactPhone")
private String contactPhone;

@Column(name="Enabled", nullable=false)
private String enabled;

@Column(name="Logo")
private String logo;

@Column(name = "CreationDate", columnDefinition="DATETIME")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date creationDate;

@Column(name = "LastUpdateDate", columnDefinition="DATETIME")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date lastUpdateDate;

//Region Constructors
private Company(){}

public Company(String companyId, String name, String contactName, String contactSurname, String contactEmail, String contactPhone,
               String enabled){

    this.companyId = companyId;
    this.name = name;
    this.contactName = contactName;
    this.contactSurname = contactSurname;
    this.contactEmail = contactEmail;
    this.contactPhone = contactPhone;
    this.enabled = enabled;

    this.creationDate = new Date();
    this.lastUpdateDate = new Date();

}
//EndRegion

//Region Getters & Setters
public String getCompanyId() {
    return companyId;
}

public void setCompanyId(String companyId) {
    this.companyId = companyId;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getContactName() {
    return contactName;
}

public void setContactName(String contactName) {
    this.contactName = contactName;
}

public String getContactSurname() {
    return contactSurname;
}

public void setContactSurname(String contactSurname) {
    this.contactSurname = contactSurname;
}

public String getContactEmail() {
    return contactEmail;
}

public void setContactEmail(String contactEmail) {
    this.contactEmail = contactEmail;
}

public String getContactPhone() {
    return contactPhone;
}

public void setContactPhone(String contactPhone) {
    this.contactPhone = contactPhone;
}

public String getEnabled() {
    return enabled;
}

public void setEnabled(String enabled) {
    this.enabled = enabled;
}

public String getLogo() {
    return logo;
}

public void setLogo(String logo) {
    this.logo = logo;
}

public Date getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate;
}

public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate;
}

public Date getLastUpdateDate() {
    return lastUpdateDate;
}

public void setLastUpdateDate(Date lastUpdateDate) {
    this.lastUpdateDate = lastUpdateDate;
}
//EndRegion
```

}

When I execute this request:

[REQUEST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByBrE.png)

I get this response:

```
{
    "cause": {
        "cause": null,
        "message": "No content to map due to end-of-input\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@1130374; line: 1, column: 0]"
    },
    "message": "Could not read an object of type class com.wipma.application.domain.Company from the request!; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input\n at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@1130374; line: 1, column: 0]"
}
```

I can´t figure out whats wrong, I suspect its something related with some field mapping but cant sort it out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post your requestmapping as well?

Comment: It means the jackson does not get any content in the request body,because you put the data in the request parameters.Just change the type how you build your request.